# socket receives `nothing`: infinite loop

Tags: python, sockets, infinite-loop

I was working on an IRC-bot as a little Python project. The bot works quite good, but is unable to stay connected for a long time. After a while, it just prints emptylines to the terminal and then pings out (because it can't process the PING from the server).

This bit of code handles the receiving part:

```
def listen(channel):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        print data
        if data != '':
            if data.split()[0] == 'PING':
                process the data
```

After a while, the bot just prints whitelines to the terminal and I have no idea why.

The full code is available here on Github: https://github.com/Silox/Python-IRC-bot/blob/master/bot.py#L101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto):

> When a `recv` returns 0 bytes, it means the other side has closed (or is in the process of closing) the connection. You will not receive any more data on this connection. Ever.

The server has closed the connection on you, probably due to a timeout since you are not replying to its pings.

Comment: Thank you - I've made edits to the code that checks for the length of the incoming data and - if zero - reconnects.

Comment: @Silox, what about sending the ack back to the server so that is does not disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

Do IRC messages always fit/fill 4K boundaries?  If not, then maybe you're missing the ping because it was split between two calls to `recv()`.  You need to collect the data returned from `recv()` and then look for the message boundary as defined by the protocol.  If you don't, then when a message doesn't align with your chosen 4K buffer you won't be processing them correctly and could miss messages.  This may be why you lose the connection in the first place.  (I don't know IRC, but this is a general principle)